# BackgroundService.StartAsync, should it complete during startup or block?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, task-parallel-library, asp.net-core-3.1, c#-8.0

I don't know if I'm missing some piece of this puzzle but as far as I'm used to working with services in general, any call to `Start` is supposed to always return so that you know your service has started.

I'm studying `BackgroundService`:
[Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)
[Implement background tasks in microservices with IHostedService and the BackgroundService class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice)

In the examples on both, they're implementing `ExecuteAsync` (which is called by `StartAsync`) using a `while loop` meaning that `ExecuteAsync` (and by extension `StartAsync`) is only ever going to return when cancelled (like when the app shuts down).

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        _logger.LogDebug($"GracePeriod task doing background work.");

        // This eShopOnContainers method is querying a database table
        // and publishing events into the Event Bus (RabbitMQ / ServiceBus)
        CheckConfirmedGracePeriodOrders();

        await Task.Delay(_settings.CheckUpdateTime, stoppingToken);
    }
}
```

This contradicts what I understand from services because how can you tell that the service has successfully started vs hanging on startup?

I'd really appreciate some clarity on this as I just can't seem to get my head around what's happening and I can't seem to find any further information specific to this.

Edit: Added call to `ExecuteAsync` from `BackgroundService` for illustration:

```
public virtual Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Store the task we're executing
    _executingTask = ExecuteAsync(_stoppingCts.Token);

    // If the task is completed then return it,
    // this will bubble cancellation and failure to the caller
    if (_executingTask.IsCompleted)
    {
        return _executingTask;
    }

    // Otherwise it's running
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Comment: Can you show an example where ExecuteAsync is "called from StartAsync"?

Comment: It's in the framework, in the BackgroundService, I've included the code for you.

Comment: Ah, that! It's calling ExecuteAsync, which returns a Task _immediately_. StartAsync then goes on to return CompletedTask itself. In other words: the call to ExecuteAsync does not block. That's why ExecuteAsync can contain an "(near-)infinte" loop to represent the lifetime of the service.

Comment: Hmmm, no, I might be ignorant but the call to ExecuteAsync is being performed synchronously and only returns after it gets a cancellation token.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: You can think of `ExecuteAsync` as _returning_ once it hits `await Task.Delay`. It continues running, as is represented by the `Task` it returns, but it's no longer blocking `StartAsync` at that point.

Comment: Ah crumbs, it's so obvious, what a Homer moment.  Hopefully my confusion will help some other sad sack like me one day.  Thanks @KirkLarkin!

Comment: @Fildor thanks, I wasn't getting the explanation since I was clearly missing the `await` piece of the puzzle which makes it all work.

Answer (score 2):

Through the magic of `async`, even though `ExecuteAsync` appears to be an infinite loop, it really returns a `Task` to the caller. The `await` on the Delay is what allows control flow to leave the `ExecuteAsync` function, with the next iteration of the loop only running after that `Task` is resolved.

If you are not used to it, it can be easy to miss.

Comment: Interesting, so if you write the `ExecuteAsync` without a sufficiently long `await` it blocks `StartAsync`. In my case, needed to change `Task.Delay(1)` with `Task.Delay(1000)`. Tough one to figure out!

Comment: It's not the duration of the task, it's the fact that you await some task that will make `HostedServiceExecutor` move on to next `BackgroundService` and unblock the startup.
A trick is to call `await Task.Yield()` whenever you want to "unblock"